# KeyValuePair nullable problem with property

Tags: c#, linq, key-value

[Code with syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hABLO.png)

Why does it not allow accessing the Key property, because I check in this block that kvp is not null ?

```
public KeyValuePair<int, int>? AddRel(int from, int to)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, int>? rel = _relations
            .Where(r => r.Key == from || r.Value == to)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    if (rel != null)
    {
        _relations.Remove(rel.Key);
    }
    _relations.Add(from, to);
    return rel;
}
```

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: `rel.Value.Key` instead of `rel.Key` (note, that `rel` is `INullable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`, not `KeyValuePair<K, V>`)

Comment: **Possible unexpected results**: Depending on the type of `_relations`, `FirstOrDefault` might be returning `default(KeyValuePair<int,int>)`, not `default(KeyValuePair<int,int>?)`. If `_relations` is of a type that implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` (not the nullable of that), the  `!= null` check will always pass, but you won't get the `Key` and `Value` that you expected. That's in addition to, and entirely separate from, Guru Stron's answer to the question at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-6.0) is actually a `struct`, so  `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>?` is actually `Nullable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` (see [`Nullable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0) struct and [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) doc) so you need to access `Nullable.Value` to get `KeyValuePair`:

```
if(rel.HasValue)
{
   var key = rel.Value.Key;
}
```

Note (thanks to [@madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection) for reminding about that) that based on the type of `_relations` `FirstOrDefault` can behave
quite differently from what you can expect cause default for value `KeyValuePair<int,int>` is not `null`:

```cs
KeyValuePair<int, int>? rel = Array.Empty<KeyValuePair<int, int>>().FirstOrDefault(); 
Console.WriteLine(rel.HasValue); // prints "True"
```

Comment: See my comment above (on the question) before you rejoice. Just because it compiles now doesn't mean that you're getting the results you expect. This only fixes the compiler error.